# Django-allauth socialaccount provider_login_url has NULL for process, scope and params

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using Django 1.10.1 and allauth 0.27.0. I have enabled social network logins for google but have **NULL** for link parameters.

Configuration:

**Settings.py (shortened)**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... skipped ...
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' }
    }  
}

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/members/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
```

**urls.py (shortened)**

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

*client id* and *secret key* are also configured on /admin/socialaccount/socialapp/

On login page I have: **(shortened)**

```
{% load i18n l10n widget_tweaks account socialaccount staticfiles %}
{% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}
{% for provider in socialaccount_providers %}
  <li>
    <a title="{{ provider.name }}" class="socialaccount_provider {{ provider.id }}" href="{% provider_login_url provider.id process=process scope=scope auth_params=auth_params %}">{{ provider.name }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

When I hit the login page I see provider's url like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/?process=NULL&scope=NULL&auth_params=NULL
```

in `{{ socialaccount_providers }}` I have `[<allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.provider.GoogleProvider object at 0x051A6E30>]`

What do I wrong?

**PS**
it's from Google:

```
Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile], invalid=[NULL]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a problem, its because I overrided base allauth template and inserted another one template inside main, in original template it was:

```
{% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
```

Just replaced

```
<li>
<a title="{{ provider.name }}" class="socialaccount_provider {{ provider.id }}" href="{% provider_login_url provider.id process=process scope=scope auth_params=auth_params %}">{{ provider.name }}</a>
</li>
```

for

```
<li>
<a title="{{ provider.name }}" class="socialaccount_provider {{ provider.id }}" href="{% provider_login_url provider.id process="login" %}">{{ provider.name }}</a>
</li>
```

`scope=NULL&auth_params=NULL` is doesn't matter here.